# geocode longitude and latitude from UK postcode?

Tags: php, geocode, postal-code

Can this be done on the fly using PHP?

I have a list of addresses with uk postcodes, but I need the longitude and latitude to use with google maps?

Comment: probably find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644035/need-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-of-postcodes-and-store-into-my-database

Comment: Ordnance Surveys CodePoint Open https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html is a free alternative to the Post Office postcode database, though you'll need to convert Nortings/Eastings to Lat/Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll generally need to pay a license for a DB of postcode to lat/lon lookups, you can find a more basic list free online (not sure how this is licensed) but this only finds the first part of the postcode (eg SW9).